# how to paginate data fetched from databse

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

lets say if there are 13 records the latest 5 or from 9-13 in the first page,
from 4-8 in second page and 1-3 in the third page

i've tried this but its for the first page only

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mysqli_login";

// Create connection
$connection= new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT name,submittedby,trn_date FROM new_record ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $fileName = $row['name'];
    $fileContents = file_get_contents("txt/$fileName");
    $poster = $row['submittedby'];
    $date = $row['trn_date'];
    echo ("posted by :$poster  |  posted date : $date");
    echo ("$fileContents");
}
?>
```

Comment: you need to use `LIMIT` but specify the page and the offset - like `LIMIT 2,10` ~ page 2 with 10 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code should be like this**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test_db";

// Create connection
$connection= new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$current_page = 1; // 1=>refer to the first page, 2=> second page and so on..
if(!empty($_GET['page_no']){
$current_page = $_GET['page_no'];
}

$to = "5"; // it is no of record which you wants to show on each page, you can change it's value as per your need.
$from = ($current_page - 1) * $to;


$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT name,submittedby,trn_date FROM new_record ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from , $to")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $fileName = $row['name'];
    $fileContents = file_get_contents("txt/$fileName");
    $poster = $row['submittedby'];
    $date = $row['trn_date'];
    echo ("posted by :$poster  |  posted date : $date");
    echo ("$fileContents");
}
?>
```

your url should be something like http://localhost/projects/?page_no=1
replace "http://localhost/projects/" with your actual url

Hope this will help!!

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an article that discusses this topic](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp). You need to offset your query based on the current page. So it will be `LIMIT 5 OFFSET <amount based on the page>`.